# Order of destruction of QML objects

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

In the following code QML :

```
Item{
  property Project proj: Project{
     id: pr
  }
  property Manager manager: Manager{
     id:o1
     project: pr 
  }
}
```

Where `Project` and `Manager` are two C++ classes such that the property `project` is a `Project*`.

Is it safe to use the project in `Manager` destructor ?
Is it possible that project gets destroyed before Manager ?
Is there any guaranty about the relative order of destruction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Qt documentation on [Component.destruction()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#destruction-signal):

> The order of running the onDestruction handlers is undefined.

So, it is ***unsafe*** to reference other components in the destructor.